# Chrome extension Window position returned by chrome.windows APIs is off (by about 8px)

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge

I am having trouble determine which (physical) monitor a Chrome window is in. This is my current solution:

```
// This is just for shorter alias
type ChrDispInfo = chrome.system.display.DisplayInfo;

private async getActiveMonitorAsync(monitors: ChrDispInfo[]) {
    const currWin = await chrome.windows.getCurrent();

    for (let monitor of monitors) {
        const a = monitor.workArea;

        if (currWin.left >= a.left && currWin.left <= a.left + a.width &&
            currWin.top >= a.top && currWin.top <= a.top + a.height) {
            return monitor;
        }
    }

    return monitors.find(q => q.isPrimary) || monitors[0];
}
```

However, I notice it doesn't always work especially when a window is maximized or when I manually move it near the top left border. The value is off by about 8px. For example, this is when I put it in a 1080x1920 monitor to the left of the primary monitor:

```
[currWin.left, currWin.top, currWin.width, currWin.height] value:
[-1088, -460, 1096, 1888]

monitor.workArea value:
{height: 1872, left: -1080, top: -452, width: 1080}
```

As you can see, the value is "off" by about 8px. I guess this is due to window border. I am running on Windows 11 Pro.

Is putting a 8px offset a good solution? Is the value different on different OS? Is there any good solution overall?

---

Update: I find it interesting that the number is then included in `width` and `height`. For example, if I want to set a window to a certain size, I have to put the offset for width and height **twice**:

```
const BorderSize = 8;

async updateWinAsync(window: ChrWin, monArea: chrome.system.display.Bounds, winSetting: Rect) {
    await chrome.windows.update(window.id, {
        left: winSetting[0] * monArea.width + monArea.left - BorderSize,
        top: winSetting[1] * monArea.height + monArea.top - BorderSize,
        width: winSetting[2] * monArea.width + BorderSize * 2,
        height: winSetting[3] * monArea.height + BorderSize * 2,
        state: "normal",
    });
}
```

Comment: Use chrome.system.display.getInfo API, it may already have that info.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, the `monitors: ChrDispInfo[]` is from that API

Comment: Sounds like a bug then...

Comment: Based on your description, I did a simple test using [window.Screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen) and found that the problem you encountered occurs when you manually drag the browser border until it adsorb to the edge of the screen. The browser window will be 7px larger (both in Edge and Chrome). But this problem doesn't occur by clicking the maximize button of the browser. I recommand you could report this issue to relvant team via [this link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks for helping me confirming (and the number). May I ask what OS you were testing on? Will report the bug :)

Comment: I tested in `Win10 20H2` and found this problem.